# fading of images in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got three images in my resource bundle. I want to fade away an existing image and load a new image in my image view every 10 seconds. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Core Animation to animate the alpha property of an image view from 1.0 to 0.0 over several seconds. This will make it appear to fade away. When the animation ends, you can change the image view's image and then either animate the alpha property back to 1.0, or just set it to 1.0 to have the image appear instantly.